# How to see tracking of emails sent through marketing cloud in sales cloud at lead & contact level?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, analytics, send-email, sales-cloud

We've implemented marketing cloud, integrated with sales cloud & enabled email tracking data transfer from marketing cloud to sales cloud.

Where can I check this data in sales cloud at lead & contact level ? 
How can I get this data at report level in sales cloud ? 
Which object is being used to store this data in sales cloud ?

Please suggest.

Comment: Remember to use either Lead or Contact ID as Subscriber Key in MC. Furthermore, tracking does not get migrated to contact once a lead is converted.

Answer (score 3):

If you have already done the integration, you are just probably missing this step: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_update_page_layouts.htm&type=5

You can find all the info about the object and how to see the data.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, Thanks for sharing link. Link explains how to show this data using visual force. I also want to export this data in the form of report. I'm not able to find report on email sends. Which report should I refer (in case any standard report exists) ?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_reports.htm&type=5